# JPA Many-to-Many Relationship with Users Entity Stored in a Different Database

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, join, many-to-many

#### TLDR;

I'm trying to create a relationship to an entity (users) stored in a different database and can't figure out how to do this in JPA.

#### Use Case

I am implementing a car service in Spring Boot/JPA. I have created an entity/table called `Car`. A car may have multiple owners (users) and a user may own multiple cars. However, the `User` table is stored in a separate user service.

Since this is a many-many relationship, I felt a `JoinTable` would be appropriate. The problem here is that there is no `User` table to join to. I just need to store the users' UUIDs in the join table, so `GET` methods can fetch all cars for a given user, or all owners of a given car.

[image]

#### Source Code

Here's an attempt at the `Car` entity. Removing the `ForeignKey` constraint allows entries to be created in the join table without causing an error due to the missing child table.

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Car {
  @Id @GeneratedValue private UUID id;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
      name = "car_owner",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "car_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
      foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="user_id", value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
  private Set<User> users;

  private String model;
  private double price;
}
```

Here's the `User` entity - required for the JPA `JoinTable`, but only used for its ID:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode()
public class User {

  @Id private UUID id;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
  @JsonIgnore
  private Set<Car> cars;
}
```

Sending the model below to a JPA Repository `save()` method creates the car and entries in the join table successfully:

```json
{
  "model": "Ford Model T",
  "price": 850.00,
  "users": [
    {"id": "e048b593-aad9-4285-b3e6-49475ad9bd1d"},
    {"id": "1d0f7b1e-bc36-4b99-80a1-8835779598ca"}
  ]
}
```

#### Problem Statement

However, when I try to retrieve all cars belonging to a specific user ID:

```java
  @Query(
      value = "select * from car c inner join car_owner co on c.id = co.car_id where co.user_id = :userId",
      nativeQuery = true)
  List<Car> findByUserId(UUID userId);
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: column user1_.id does not exist
> Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->Car["users"])]

How can I read back the list of cars for a given user? Am I going about this the wrong way? I'm open to other implementations.

Comment: is it stored in same database but different schema or it is a different database server?

Comment: If its same database but different schema, you can create a view in your current schema and query multiple schemas. But if its a different database, even I am not sure

Comment: @SridharPatnaik The users database is not created yet, but I'd like to use a microservice architecture, which would require these two services to be decoupled (different database).

Comment: If the users are managed by another service you should not have a user entity in your car service. So just use @ElementCollection private Set<UUID> owners

Comment: @vincendep You're right, I need to drop the `User` entity and the `JoinTable`. But I'm still not clear how to map the `car_owner` table and columns with `@ElementCollection`. Will keep searching in this direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @vincendep mentioned, the solution is to drop the `User` entity and replace the `users` property in the `Car` entity with the following:

```java
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "car_owner", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "car_id"))
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Set<UUID> owners;
```

This will still use the `car_owner` join table. A car can be created with multiple users with the following model:

```json
{
  "model": "Ford Model T",
  "price": 850.00,
  "owners": [
    "32a7967d-8580-418d-b53a-221ed0c52222",
    "a708455c-c37c-4712-a7ce-59c9be5a5eb5"
  ]
}
```

You can query cars by user ID as follows (credit to @vincendep):

```java
@Query(value = "from Car c where :ownerId member of c.owners")
List<Car> findByUserId(UUID ownerId);
```

Comment: Also the query should be something like this
@Query(
      value = "FROM Car c WHERE :owner MEMBER OF c.owners")
  List<Car> findByUserId(UUID owner);

Comment: Thanks a million for your help @vincendep! Solution is much cleaner. I will definitely add this to my JPA toolbox.